# primitive recursive conditional

Tags: functions, recursion

I am confronted with the assertion that the following expression describes the conditional:

$\text{Cond}\left[ t, f, g \right] = \text{Pr} \left[pr^2_1, pr^4_2 \right] \circ(f,g,t)$.

This is meant to be equivalent to this:

$\text{cond}(f,g,t) = \cases{f\quad \text{if}\ t = 0\\g \quad \text{else}}$

Well, first of all, composing $Pr$ with $f, g, t$ is not the same as applying it to $f, g, t$ as arguments, right? So, if $Pr$ takes 3 arguments, then what are these, if not $f, g, t$?

Secondly, there needs to be some variable $y \in \mathbb{N}$ to be decremented during the recursion that needs to be passed as an argument. If $f, g, t$ are all functions, where is $y$ coming from?

Lastly I don't know how I have to interpret the composition of $Pr$ with $f, g, t$... what would the resulting expression look like?

So, how is the primitive recursive conditional expression to be understood?

## Edit

Following the explanation in the answer, I still have an issue with this. I tried doing an example by hand but  immediately get stuck:

The program computes `if (x == 1) then s x else p x`

$cond[t,f,g] = Pr[pr^2_1, pr^4_2] \circ (f, g, t)$

Let

$f = s$ the sucessor function

$g = p$ the predecessor function

$t = \cases{x \mapsto 0 \quad if\ x = 1\\ x \mapsto 1 \quad else} $

$
\begin{aligned}
&cond[t,f,g]\ (3) &= \quad &(Pr[pr^2_1, pr^4_2] \circ (f, g, t))\ (3)\\
&                 &= \quad &pr^4_2\ ???
\end{aligned}
$

My issue now is the following:

by composition I would now apply $f, g, t$ to $x = 3$.

So I would end up with

$
\begin{aligned}
&cond[t,f,g]\ (3) &= \quad &(Pr[pr^2_1, pr^4_2] \circ (f, g, t))\ (3)\\
&                 &= \quad &pr^4_2\ (f(3), g(3), t(3)-1, cond(f(3), g(3), t(3)-1)\\
&\text{which is equal to:}&&\\
&                 &= \quad &pr^4_2\ (s\ 3, p\ 3, 0, cond(s\ 3, p\ 3, 0)\\
&\dots
\end{aligned}
$

Somehow this feels incorrect... is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your source defines $\operatorname{Pr}$ with a different ordering of the inputs from the one to which I’m accustomed. It appears that if $h=\operatorname{Pr}\left(\operatorname{pr}_1^2,\operatorname{pr}_2^4\right)$, then $h$ is the ternary function such that

$$\begin{align*}
h(x_1,x_2,0)&=\operatorname{pr}_1^2(x_1,x_2)=x_1\\
h(x_1,x_2,y+1)&=\operatorname{pr}_2^4\big(x_1,x_2,y,h(x_1,x_2,y)\big)=x_2\;.
\end{align*}$$

Clearly this amounts to saying that

$$h(x_1,x_2,y)=\begin{cases}
x_1,&\text{if }y=0\\
x_2,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Now assume that $f,g$, and $t$ are $m$-ary functions for some $m\in\Bbb N$, and for convenience write $\vec x$ for $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\rangle$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\big(h\circ(f,g,t)\big)(x_1,\ldots,x_m)&=h\big(f(\vec x),g(\vec x),t(\vec x)\big)\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
f(\vec x),&\text{if }t(\vec x)=0\\
g(\vec x),&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

**Added:** It would be easier to follow the example in the edit if you simplified the notation, but it looks fine. Using my abbreviation, it’s simply this:

$$\begin{align*}
h\big(f(3),g(3),t(3)\big)&=h(4,2,1)\\
&=\operatorname{pr}_2^4\big(4,2,0,h(4,2,0)\big)\\
&=2
\end{align*}$$

This is clearly the correct value of the conditional when $x=3$. If you’re worried by the presence of $h(4,2,0)$ in the penultimate line, note that it doesn’t actually matter *what* that fourth operand is, since $\operatorname{pr}_2^4$ always ignores it anyway.

Comment: thanks, I have edited my question because I have doubts whether I understand the explanation correctly. Can you tell me whether my example computation is correct or incorrect (it stops midway. That I am aware of).

Comment: @user3578468: My response was long enough that I added it to the answer, since I had to correct a typo anyway.